# Value of self in a method defined on singleton class

Tags: ruby, singleton, metaprogramming

Why is `self`, in the method (`singleton2`) defined on a singleton class, not equal to that singleton class like in the other three cases?

```
    class A
      def self.singleton1
        class << self
          self
        end
      end

      class << self
        def singleton2
          self
        end
      end
    end

    def singleton3
      class << A
        self
      end
    end

    p [A.singleton1, A.singleton1.object_id]           # [#<Class:A>, 70003841656620]
    p [A.singleton2, A.singleton2.object_id]           # [A, 70003841656640]
    p [singleton3, singleton3.object_id]               # [#<Class:A>, 70003841656620]
    p [A.singleton_class, A.singleton_class.object_id] # [#<Class:A>, 70003841656620]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll explain it part by part.

```
 def self.singleton1
   class << self
     self
   end
 end
```

Here, `self` inside the method is `A`. Now within the method you are creating another scope, which is the scope of the singleton class of `A`, using `class << self`. And the `self` of the singleton class is being returned when you called `A.singeton1`, as `self` inside the singleton class of `A` is the last statement of the method `singleton1`.

```
class << self
  def singleton2
    self
  end
end
```

Here, `self` inside the body of the singleton class of `A` is, *singleton class* itself. Now you defined a singleton method `singleton2` on class `A`. Inside the method, last expression is `self`, which is always will be set to `receiver`, here it is `A`. One more thing, `def singleton2` creates a new scope, which is different from the scope of the singleton class of `A`.

As per the above explanation, I hope the below code output must be clear to you :-

```
class A
  def self.singleton1
    class << self
      self
    end
  end

  class << self
    def singleton2
      self
    end
  end
end

A.singleton2 # => A 
A.singleton1 # => #<Class:A>
```

output `A` and `#<Class:A>` clearly telling, why the `object_id`s were different.

From the above 2 explanations, it is clear what is going on for `singleton3`.